# nameserver and nameservers tags

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Can [nameserver](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/nameserver) and [nameservers](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/nameservers) tags be merged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've merged them (the synonym `nameservers` -> `nameserver` was automatically created).